# Excel Categorize Times of day

Tags: excel

I am trying to create an excel function that categorizes the time of day.
I have a column of DateTimes, Format: 3/3/2017 13:30 (but can change the format if needed). I need a second column declaring "ON" for the hours 9 pm to 5 am, "AM" for 5 am to 9 am, "BH" for 9 am to 5 pm, and "PM" for the hours 5 pm to 9 pm. I need weekends too but I figure I can pull those manually.

Result would look like (where I have column 1 and need to calculate column 2):

```
DateTime          Time period
3/3/2017 13:30       BH
3/3/2017 17:30       PM
3/4/2017 3:30        ON
3/5/2017 5:30        AM
```

Comment: Hi all. Not sure how much it matters but I am choosing Adams answer based on the fact that its the one I'm using. All have proven correct but Adams had the weekend bit that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can save a few characters by only testing one end of each range. Once we have tested a value for less than 5 am, we no longer need to test to see if it is greater than 5 am.  (The `AND(` statements aren't necessary.)

```
=IF(HOUR(A1)<5,"ON",IF(HOUR(A1)<9,"AM",IF(HOUR(A1)<17,"BH",IF(HOUR(A1)<21,"PM","ON"))))
```

If you want to detect weekends, wrap the whole thing in a weekend test.  Two methods presented:

1. The better approach, suggested by @ScottCraner in the comments:

`=IF(weekday(a1,2)>5,"WEEKEND","THE WHOLE THING")`

The first argument for `weekday(` is obviously the date we are testing.  The second forces Monday to be the first day of the week, which leaves Sat & Sun as the last two.

Combined with the rest, we would get:

```
=IF(weekday(a1,2)>5,"WEEKEND",IF(HOUR(A1)<5,"ON",IF(HOUR(A1)<9,"AM",IF(HOUR(A1)<17,"BH",IF(HOUR(A1)<21,"PM","ON")))))
```

2. An unnecessarily long, and somewhat fragile approach (breaks in non-English)

`=IF(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"ddd"),1)="S","WEEKEND","THE WHOLE THING")`

This works because `TEXT(A1,"ddd")` formats the date as the three-letter day of week.  In English, at least, both weekend days starts with an "S", and we use `left(` to grab that first letter.

Together, it would end up looking like:

```
=IF(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"ddd"),1)="S","WEEKEND",IF(HOUR(A1)<5,"ON",IF(HOUR(A1)<9,"AM",IF(HOUR(A1)<17,"BH",IF(HOUR(A1)<21,"PM","ON")))))
```

Comment: You weekend is great, unless the language is not English,  `IF(WEEKDAY(A1,2)>5,"Weekend",...` would probably be better and more robust in a international forum. and it is shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Make a table with the lower time and expected out put:

[image]

Then a simple VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(MOD(A2,1),F:G,2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to show a different way:

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(A2,A2),CHOOSE(SUM((({"5:00";"9:00";"17:00";"21:00"}*1)<MOD(A2,1))*1)+1,"ON","AM","BH","PM","ON"),"WEEKEND")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Can be extended as you like without getting in trouble of the bracket-limit.
Also like the Scott's answer: this works with times like `17:43`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A little long, but works:

```
=IF(AND(HOUR(A2)>=9,HOUR(A2)<17),"BH",IF(AND(HOUR(A2)>=17,HOUR(A2)<21),"PM",IF(AND(HOUR(A2)>=5,HOUR(A2)<9),"AM","ON")))
```

[image]